# how to separate a string by comma in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to print as follows in javascript ?

if my input is "smart"
then my output could be "s,m,a,r,t"

I've tried by using this logic but i got the output as
s,m,a,r,t,

```js
let a = " ";
str = userInput[0];
console.log(str);
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  a = a + str[i] + ",";
}
console.log(a.trim());
```

Comment: `'smart'.split('').join()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+split+word+into+characters+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `const a = userInput[0]?.trim().split("").toString() || ""`

Comment: @Angeshwari Feel free to delete this massive dupe

Answer (score -1):

You can use the split method in js

```js
var str = "smart";
var res = str.split("").join();
console.log(res)
   //if you want it to remain an array don't do the join
```